# C shell printing output infinitely without stopping at gets()

Tags: shell, unix, operating-system

I am trying to use the SIGCHLD handler but for some reason it prints of the command I gave infinitely. If I remove the struct act it works fine.

Can anyone take a look at it, I am not able to understand what the problem is.
Thanks in advance!!

```
    /* Simplest dead child cleanup in a SIGCHLD handler. Prevent zombie processes
   but dont actually do anything with the information that a child died. */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef char *string;

/* SIGCHLD handler. */
static void sigchld_hdl (int sig)
{
    /* Wait for all dead processes.
     * We use a non-blocking call to be sure this signal handler will not
     * block if a child was cleaned up in another part of the program. */
    while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0) {
    }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction act;
    int i;
    int nbytes = 100;
    char my_string[nbytes];
    string arg_list[5];
    char *str;
    memset (&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_handler = sigchld_hdl;

    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, 0)) {
        perror ("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }

while(1){

    printf("myshell>> ");
    gets(my_string);
    str=strtok(my_string," \n");
    arg_list[0]=str;
    i =1;
    while ( (str=strtok (NULL," \n")) != NULL){
            arg_list[i]= str;
            i++;
        }
    if (i==1)
        arg_list[i]=NULL;
    else
        arg_list[i+1]=NULL;

     pid_t child_pid;
    child_pid=fork();
    if (child_pid == (pid_t)-1){
        printf("ERROR OCCURED");
        exit(0);
        }

    if(child_pid!=0){
        printf("this is the parent process id is %d\n", (int) getpid());
        printf("the child's process ID is %d\n",(int)child_pid);

    }
    else{
        printf("this is the child process, with id %d\n", (int) getpid());
        execvp(arg_list[0],arg_list);
        printf("this should not print - ERROR occured");
        abort();
    }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: even fgets() gives me the same problem!!

Comment: The use of `gets` is not the source of the symptoms you're seeing, but `gets` is inherently unsafe. It provides no way to specify how big the target array is. If someone running your program types more than 100 characters on a line, you'll have a buffer overrun, resulting in undefined (i.e., arbitrarily bad) behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run your code, and am merely hypothesizing:

`SIGCHLD` is arriving and interrupting `fgets` (I'll just pretend you didn't use `gets`).  `fgets` returns before actually reading any data, `my_string` contains the tokenized list that it had on the previous loop, you fork again, enter `fgets`, which is interrupted before reading any data, and repeat indefinitely.

In other words, check the return value of `fgets`.  If it is NULL and has set `errno` to EINTR, then call fgets again.  (Or set `act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART`.)